# renaming the file name dyanamically daily basis incrementing with count of file in file name

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have BIP report extract which has to get renamed dyanamically on daily basis with autoincremented count of file appended with the dyanamic file name, for Ex: Account_2019-01-19-15.28.12_1 .csv 
in this example, Account - filename,2019-01-19-15.28.12 -> systimestamp , 1 is count of file which i need to append. any ideas will be appreciated

In bursting Query, i had sql query for parameter 5 as follows,

'Account'||replace(replace(replace(substr(systimestamp,1,19),'-',''),':',''),' ','')|| '.csv' as "PARAMETER5"

but in this before '.csv'  i have to append auto incrementing count of file on daily basis. Please provide any ideas

Answer (score 0):

can you create an oracle sequence and give the next_val before '.csv'

```
'Account'||replace(replace(replace(substr(systimestamp,1,19),'-',''),':',''),' ','')||seq.next_val|| '.csv'
```

another option is to use a variable to get the count of files and use that variable in your concatenation

```
'Account'||replace(replace(replace(substr(systimestamp,1,19),'-',''),':',''),' ','')||v_count| '.csv'
```

or

create a file log table and take the number of files already extracted and add 1 to that and use in new file name